# Div with position absolute and lower z-index is showing on top of a higher z-index(fixed position)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Alright... I have a nav menu that when you scroll down past it, it changes to a fixed menu on top that accompanies the page.

But for some reason, I have a div on the page that has an absolute position and a lower z-index than the menu but it still shows up on top of the menu...

Here's the function that sets the menu to fixed past a certain point.

```
$(function(){
    var pos = $('#nav').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if( $(window).scrollTop() > pos ) {
            $('#nav').parent().parent().css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px', background: '#fff', width: '100%', 'z-index': 9002, left:0});
        } else {
            $('#nav').parent().parent().css({position: 'static', top: '0px', background: 'none', width: '100%', 'z-index': 1});
        }
    });
});
```

This is the div that is showing on top when it shouldn't...

```
.header {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0; }
```

Also, [here](http://www.incocomz.net/pages/aplica#) you can see an example of it happening as you scroll down the page.

Comment: Are you sure the `.header` css you've posted is correct? According to my debugging within firefox, I noticed that the `.header` class actually has a z-index of 9001. Looking at the raw html txt for you file, I found CSS for your `.header` applying that z-index also. Is this a bug in my browser? If not, that would be what's causing your problems.

Comment: Sorry apparently I edited only locally. Anyways it wouldn't make a difference as the menu has 9002 z-index! But I fixed it, it now only has 1 as I said in the main post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Apply a **position:relative** on `<div id="page-content">`
2. Change the **z-index** on `<header class="site-header">` to **2**